# Column Header Text can't set due to index was out of range

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I have two methods that will run after a button click, `bgEqptRec()` and `receiveHeader()`. The `bgEqptRec()`  contains the `recieveHeader()` who set the column header title. But it cannot set due to index was out of range. I'm pretty sure that I'm using the right number of the index from SQL Server. Here's the code:

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        bgEqptRec();
}

private void bgEqptRec()
        {
            receiveHeader();
            gvSearch.DataSource = null;
            using (var connect = connection.getConnection())
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM receive WHERE rec_stat='IN' AND rec_date BETWEEN '" + dtpFrom.Text + "' AND '" + dtpTo.Text + "'"))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = connect;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                        {
                            da.Fill(dt);
                            gvSearch.DataSource = dt;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

private void receiveHeader()
        {
            gvSearch.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Supplier";
            gvSearch.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Invoice";
            gvSearch.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Brand";
            gvSearch.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Model";
            gvSearch.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Equipment";
            gvSearch.Columns[5].HeaderText = "Serial No.";
            gvSearch.Columns[6].HeaderText = "Price";
            gvSearch.Columns[7].HeaderText = "PO No.";
            gvSearch.Columns[8].HeaderText = "Release Date";
            gvSearch.Columns[9].HeaderText = "Release By";
            gvSearch.Columns[10].HeaderText = "Status";
        }
```

The error given by VS was "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."

Comment: Are you getting the error in this line:  `gvSearch.Columns[0]`

Comment: Do a simple test to see what are the columns available - either in debug and watch gvSearch.Columns, or just loop through and print each columnn index and field name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope that the issue is that: at the Time of calling the `receiveHeader();` method the dataSource of the grid is either null or few columns less that 11, as you are taking `Columns[10]`. So I suggest you to call the method after  assigning the DataSource for the Grid. Make sure that the query returns at least 11 columns. Which means the code will be like this:

```
using (var connect = connection.getConnection())
{
   using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM receive WHERE rec_stat='IN' AND rec_date BETWEEN '" + dtpFrom.Text + "' AND '" + dtpTo.Text + "'"))
   {
      // rest of code
      gvSearch.DataSource = dt;
    }
}
// call the method here since the grid is populated

receiveHeader();
```